# DFS initial replication - not enough storage is available to process this command (target on Synology NAS)

Tags: dfs, dfs-r, synology

On a Windows 2003 SBS server, I am trying to replicate a share via DFS to a Synology File Server.

In the Configure Replication Wizard, the target has a red X across it with the message "Unknown: Not enough storage is available to process this command."

The existing share only has about 15 GB of data in it, with nearly 2 TB disk space left on the Synology Share (DS1812+/DSM 5.1). Is it possible that Synology does not report the available space back correctly? The target share is set up with Windows ACLs, and Administrators and Users alike can access the share and store or retrieve files happily.

I'm running out of ideas on how to troubleshoot this any further, and would appreciate some ideas on how to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know DFS-R requires having a Windows Server to act as an replication partner, and I'd be surprised if the Synology NASs supported it.

I've never tried setting up a replication group with a server that didn't have the DFS-R role services installed, never mind a server that isn't running Windows.

Comment: I have other shared folders that are set up on the NAS, integrated with DFS. Although they are not replicated, simply other targets. Maybe I can't, then...

Comment: Yeah, you can add targets on any CIFS share for sure, but I'm almost 100% sure the replication portion requires a Windows Server of some sort since there's services that run locally to perform the replication.